# Построение правильной архитектуры таблицы

Tags: база-данных

Существует вот такая схема таблиц БД:

[image: Схема таблиц]

Но возникает проблема, когда мы выполняем INSERT в таблицу `BUSINESS_PROCESSES_ROUTE`, ключ проверяется только по `SYSTEM_ABONENT_ID` и `BP_ID`. Таким образом мы можем вставить в таблицу `BUSINESS_PROCESS_ROUTE` абонента, который реально не относится к той системе, которая указана в `BUSINESS_PROCESSES`.

Не проверяется связь между `SYSTEM_ID` (таблица `SYSTEM_ID`) и `SENDER_SYSTEM_ID, RECEIVER_SYSTEM_ID` (таблица `BUSINESS_PROCESSES`).

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Боюсь такие проверки возможны только триггерами

Comment: Схема имхо неверна. Если Вы правильно описываете связи, то оба поля SYSTEM_ID в таблице BUSINESS_PROCESSES  вообще лишние, их следует удалить и определять на основании оставшихся связей.

Comment: @Akina А мне модель подсказала, что в BUSINESS_PROCESSES этими полями описано правило, кто именно может участвовать в данном процессе. А в route как раз это правило должно выполниться. Если это так, то  эти поля необходимы.

Comment: @Mike, Да, Вы правы.